# Switching on a generic type?

Tags: swift, generics

Is it possible to switch on a generic type in Swift?

Here's an example of what I mean:

```
func doSomething<T>(type: T.Type) {
    switch type {
    case String.Type:
        // Do something
        break;
    case Int.Type:
        // Do something
        break;
    default:
        // Do something
        break;
    }
}
```

When trying to use the code above, I get the following errors:

```
Binary operator '~=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String.Type.Type' and 'T.Type'
Binary operator '~=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int.Type.Type' and 'T.Type'
```

Is there a way to switch on a type, or to achieve something similar? (calling a method with a generic and performing different actions depending on the type of the generic)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need the `is` pattern:

```
func doSomething<T>(type: T.Type) {
    switch type {
    case is String.Type:
        print("It's a String")
    case is Int.Type:
        print("It's an Int")
    default:
        print("Wot?")
    }
}
```

Note that the `break` statements are usually not needed, there is no
"default fallthrough" in Swift cases.

Comment: I get a strange warning when using `switch type`, however `switch T.self` works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @jackwilsdon: Strange, I tested it in Xcode 7.0.1 and got no warnings.

Comment: I am using a playground, however after reloading the playground the warning was gone. Thanks!

Comment: @jackwilsdon: My personal experience is that the Playground is great to play with *working* code. If anything "unexpected" happens, switch to a compiled project, the compiler diagnostics and debugging facilities are better.

Comment: So how do you fix this when you try to assign a `tintColor` (i.e. for `UIButton`) ? This makes `T` an `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<UIColor>`, how to check against those?

Comment: Warning!  `is` accepts subclasses!  Like, if `Parent` -> `Child` -> `Grandchild`, and you have `case is` statements for them in order, it'll always be `Parent` that triggers.  (If you reverse the order, it looks like it works alright - kindof a hack, though.)  Anybody know how to get it to check exact equality?

Comment: @Erhannis: I would say that is expected behaviour, because a Child “is” also a Paren. For equality you can check `if type == Parent.self`.

Comment: @MartinR It's only expected if you already know that's what it does.  `switch` and `case` normally check for equality, and since OP asked "Is it possible to switch on a generic type in Swift?" I'd assume they were expecting equality, further supported by their example.  I just wanted to warn anybody reading the answer that it doesn't check equality.  And yes, you can use `if type == Parent.self`, as I have done in my own code - but then it's not a `case` statement, anymore.