# How to make switch on Type

Tags: swift, types, switch-statement

I would like to make a switch statement on Type of given protocol. Lets say I have:

```
protocol A {}

struct SA: A {}
struct SB: A {}

let aself: A.Type = SA.self
let bself: A.Type = SB.self

switch aself {
case is SA:
    break
default:
    break
}
```

Can I somehow make such switch work? This gives me warning that such conversion always fails. Can this be done somehow?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203689/switching-on-a-generic-type

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: A lot to explain. In shortcut I have a base engine that defines some objects behavior and on top of this base class I can create working engines that display this content using different technologies. Engines uses different data types for specific tasks, and base is calling functions using these types. I tried to use generics first, but this didn't work well, so dynamic types are better solution for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
switch aself {
case is SA.Type:
    print("is SA.Type")
default:
    print("Unknown type")
}
```

Or this:

```
switch ObjectIdentifier(aself) {
case ObjectIdentifier(SA.self):
    print("is SA.Type")
default:
    print("Unknown type")
}
```

---

(Some code explaining different behavior for subclasses as I commented below.)

```
class CA: A {}
class CAA: CA {}

let caaself: A.Type = CAA.self

switch caaself {
case is CA.Type:
    print("is CA.Type") //->is CA.Type
default:
    print("Unknown type")
}

switch ObjectIdentifier(caaself) {
case ObjectIdentifier(CA.self):
    print("is CA.Type")
default:
    print("Unknown type") //->Unknown type
}
```

You may need to use `ObjectIdentifier` when you want to exclude subclasses in your type matching. (There may be other ways, but I do not think of any, now.)

Comment: Thanks :). Thats what I needed. Before I tried with SB.self instead of .Type.

Comment: @DamianDudycz, using meta types is not an easy thing. Please remember the two codes above show different behavior when used for classes (and subclasses).

Comment: You mean that it will pass for superclasses when tested against them? Or something else?

Comment: @DamianDudycz, when `CA` is a class, `case is CA.Type` matches for all subclasses of `CA`. But `case ObjectIdentifier(CA.self)` matches only for `CA.self`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you'll also want to use the casted type value, in this situation you can use some pattern matching:

```
switch aself {
case let a as SA.Type:
    break
default:
    break
}
```

If you don't want to use the casted value:

```
switch aself {
case let _ as SA.Type:
    break
default:
    break
}
```