# Swift - switch on metatypes

Tags: swift

Option 1:

```
func getKeyByType<T:Decodable>(type: T.Type) -> String {

    if (type == [String].self){
        return "storageKey"
    }

    return "nothing"
}
```

Option 2:

```
func getKeyByType<T:Decodable>(type: T.Type) -> String {

    switch type {
    case [String].self:
        return "storageKey"
    default:
        return "nothing"
    }
}
```

//

```
getKeyByType(type: [String].self)
```

First method works properly, but on second I get compile error:

> Expression pattern of type '[String].Type' cannot match values of type
>   'T.Type'

How to get switch works with metatypes?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33203689/switching-on-a-generic-type

Comment: If you really want `case [String].self` to work, you could provide an overload of `~=` that compares two `Any.Type` values, e.g `func ~= (pattern: Any.Type, value: Any.Type) -> Bool { return pattern == value }`. Then if [SE-0090](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0090-remove-dot-self.md) ever happens you could say `case [String]` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution:

```
switch type {
case is [String].Type :
    return "storageKey"
default:
    return "nothing"
}
```